# How could I output IAM role and use that in another stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've two stacks called **"createIAMRole"**, **"createElasticSearch"** and **"createdLambda"**. What I want is I want to use IAM Role ARN from first stack called **"createIAMRole"** in both **"createElasticSearch"** and **"createdLambda"**.

**createIAMRole**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: >
  blah.

Resources:
  myIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      ..
      ..
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - dynamodb:*
                Resource: "*"
          PolicyName: "myIAMRolePolicy"

Outputs:
  myIAMRole:
    Description: myIAMRole to use Stacks
    Value: !Ref myIAMRole
```

**"createElasticSearch"**

```
Resources:
  ElasticsearchDomain:
    Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
    Properties:
      ..
      ..
      AccessPolicies:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              AWS: 
                - >>> THERE IS I WANT TO ADD <<<
            Action: "es:*"
            Resource: "*"
      AdvancedOptions:
        rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: "true"
```

Please let me know how to do it, thanks.

Comment: See [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) in AWS CF documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
For the createIAMRole you need to export the output: 
Outputs:   myIAMRole:
    Description: myIAMRole to use Stacks
    Value: !Ref myIAMRole
    Export:
      Name: myIAMRole

And for the createElasticSearch you need to "ImportValue": 
Fn::ImportValue:
   !Sub "${myIAMStackName}-myIAMRole"

More Information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html
```

Comment: that's completely enough? Just like "myIAMRole**.ARN**"

Comment: Yes, that's basically what you need. You export outputs from one template and import them using `!ImportValue` in another template. The answer is pretty on spot.